# API SOAP V2 CatalogProductList Visual Basic VB Multi Filters

Tags: api, soap, filter, vb.net

I have the next code to obtain product list from Magento API in VB.

```
    Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
    Dim sesionID = pws.login("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    Dim result

    Dim filters As New MagentoService.filters
    Dim complexFilter(0) As MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0).key = "manufacturer"
    Dim assEnt As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
    With assEnt
        .key = "manufacturer"
        .value = "34"
    End With
    complexFilter(0).value = assEnt

    filters.complex_filter = complexFilter
    result = pws.catalogProductList(sesionID, filters, "0")
```

And all works fine, I get the product list from manufacturer 34. But now I want to get the product from **manufacturer** 34 and **set** 9. I can't code the apropiate filter.

Any one can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea about VB, but couldn't you just build a similar variable as `assEnt` and make `complexFilter(1).value = yourNewVar`?

Comment: I try it before but don't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, you are right Marius. See detail.

```
    Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
    Dim sesionID = pws.login("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
    Dim result

    Dim filters As New MagentoService.filters
    Dim complexFilter(2) As MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0).key = "manufacturer"
    Dim assEnt As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
    With assEnt
        .key = "manufacturer"
        .value = "34"
    End With
    complexFilter(0).value = assEnt

    complexFilter(1) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(1).key = "set"
    Dim assEnt2 As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
    With assEnt2
        .key = "set"
        .value = "9"
    End With
    complexFilter(1).value = assEnt2

    filters.complex_filter = complexFilter
    result = pws.catalogProductList(sesionID, filters, "0")
```

Now I get SOAP answer filtered by **set** and **manufacturer**.

Thanks